# macOS window with integrated title bar and toolbar?

Tags: macos, interface-builder, osx-yosemite

In macOS how can I create a window with an "integrated title bar and toolbar" in Xcode and/or Interface Builder?

This is the "fat title bar" type of window that was added to apps such as Safari and Calendar in OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Unified title bar and toolbar plus other gadgets.

> [macOS Human Interface Guidelines: Title Bar and Toolbar](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/window-anatomy/)
>
> A toolbar, when included, resides beneath the title bar **(or is integrated with the title bar)** and includes controls—known as toolbar items—that provide quick access to frequently used commands and features.
>
> [image: Integrated title bar and toolbar]
>
> *Integrated title bar and toolbar*

Comment: I added an edit to add quotes and images from the HIG + modernize this question from the Yosemite era. Let me know if anything should be rolled back!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

1. Create a standard toolbar.
2. When the window loads, set `titleVisibility` to hidden:

   ```
   // Objective-C
   window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;

   // Swift
   window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
   ```

Comment: I can confirm that this does indeed achieve the desired behaviour. For a full example, see the 'Sample Maps' demo in VisualEffectPlayground (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/VisualEffectPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014632)

Comment: Do you tried "NSWindowTitleHidden" in a Swift project? Because I get 'Use of unresolved identifier...', but in Objective-C everything its ok.

Comment: @MacsenLiviu I haven't but I guess it's namespaced somehow. Search the docs for the right namespace.

Comment: @porneL Yes it is NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden

Comment: Partly related, but probably not question-worthy: where an app has been designed to hide the title, might there be any way for an end user to override – to show the title (presumably in a traditional title bar)? A third-party hack, maybe? Thanks.

Comment: For those in the future, put the following in your WindowController: `window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden`

Comment: @GrahamPerrin There is no override for users. It may be possible to hack/patch Cocoa to disable the `titleVisibility` property.

Comment: This option is available in Yosemite only. Is there any way to achieve this in mevericks ?

Comment: This way is working well, but did you achieve to have your titlebar/toolbar unified fittings its subviews? Whatever the size of them, mine is keeping the regular height.

Comment: What to do for document-based apps where it's useful to keep the title?

Comment: @Bruno You could create a toolbar element with a custom view that displays the title, but that would be a poor substitute. If you need the title then the best solution is not to use this style.

Comment: Yes that's an idea, not sure how difficult it would be to mimic a document window's popup title.

Comment: Cool. For those who don't know, like me, to add a toolbar you need to drag one in IB over the NSWindow.

Comment: **Additonally**, make sure the `NSButton`s inside each item are of style "Texture Rounded" in the attributes inspector: this style highlights in a light shade of gray, exactly like those in Safari. The default style "Push", on the other hand, higlights in Blue or Graphite (depending on System Preferences/General).

Comment: @tofutim As of Xcode 10, you can do it in IB by turning on the “Hide Title” checkbox under the window's title in the window's Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 13):

As of Xcode 10, you can do this in your XIB or storyboard by turning on the “Hide Title” check box under the window's title in the window's Attributes Inspector.

[image: xib demo]

Note also that you should use the “Textured Rounded” style for toolbar buttons.

Answer (score 12):

In your window controller's `windowDidLoad()`:

```
window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
```