# Yosemite-style toolbar for document based apps?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, osx-yosemite

Looking for a way to create a Yosemite-style toolbar but retain the default functionality of the titlebar of document based apps.

Here's one way to create a Yosemite-style titlebar:
[macOS window with integrated title bar and toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023000/how-can-i-create-yosemite-style-unified-toolbar-in-interface-builder)

Which requires hiding the titlebar. Is there a way to get this look and feel but retain the titlebar view which contains:

- the filename
- if the file has been edited
- the fancy renaming popover?

These are the controls we'd like to retain:

[image: d]

Comment: Have you found a way for implementing this feature?