# Use combined titlebar + toolbar while preserving title visibility

Tags: macos, interface-builder, nswindow, nstoolbar

The System Preferences app feature a combined title bar and toolbar with vertically centered buttons and the title. I am trying to mimic this exactly in my app. I have been able to combine the title bar and toolbar using Interface Builder (on the NSWindow check Title Bar and Unified Title and Toolbar), but this does not center the content vertically. I discovered via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023000/how-can-i-create-yosemite-style-unified-toolbar-in-interface-builder/24026771#24026771) you can simply set the window's `titleVisibility` to `NSWindowTitleHidden` which will vertically center the stoplight buttons. Unfortunately this of course hides the title. How can one vertically center content in the unified titlebar/toolbar and also show the window's title just like System Preferences - either in IB or programmatically?

[image]

Comment: Any status update on this?

Comment: @DalmazioBrisinda Just posted the only solution I found

Answer (score 1):

I ended up setting `titleVisibility` to `NSWindowTitleHidden` and manually created an `NSView` that contains an `NSTextField` that mimics the standard title appearance, providing that to the window's `addTitlebarAccessoryViewController` method. Still would like to find a better solution to use the default title appearance, if possible.

Comment: Thanks @joey. I'll post a different solution shortly.

Comment: but this doesn't work for document apps cause document title has more native functionality

Answer (score -1):

I used [WAYAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/weAreYeah/WAYAppStoreWindow/) on GitHub to do this. I created a fork of the [WAYWindow](https://github.com/dbrisinda/WAYWindow) subproject to vertically centre the document title since this wasn't supported. This means any applied themes/appearances are honoured.