# wxWidgets Mac OS X Yosemite-style unified toolbar

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

How to make such kind of OS X toolbar with wxWidgets 3.1?

https://monosnap.com/file/ZMbvh8uVng0J54WgOqOcXDKKr1g9sF

[How can I create Yosemite-style unified toolbar in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023000/how-can-i-create-yosemite-style-unified-toolbar-in-interface-builder)

I can access a reference to a native NSWindow:

```
auto *nativeWindow = wxWindow::MacGetTopLevelWindowRef();
nativeWindow->NSWindow->titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
```

But calling `->titleVisibility` above gives "wxWidgets-3.1.0/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp:647:17: Member access into incomplete type 'NSWindow'" and I can't @import / #include NSWindow to my .cpp program because it's objective-c header

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename the source file to have a `.mm` extension or explicitly request using Objective-C++ when compiling it using `-x` compiler option. Another possibility, which can be useful if you also need to compile the same file under other platforms, is to include the `.cpp` file from the OS X-specific `.mm` one, e.g. wxWidgets own [widgets sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/samples/widgets/native_wrapper.mm) does it like this.