# Mac OS mixed title bar

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, titlebar

How can I create a title bar like this?

I mean a title bar that is visible in one part of the window and invisible in another part.

[image: title bar]

Comment: Are you sure the thing on the right is an actual title bar? Could it just be a gray area with some controls in it that looks like a title bar?

Comment: Possibly an [`NSSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nssplitview) with [unified toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023000/how-can-i-create-yosemite-style-unified-toolbar-in-interface-builder) on the master (left) view

Comment: @jjs, maybe, but can I set style for control like this? with bottom shadow, for example.